# Error Initiating one-to-one chat using getstream.io

Tags: javascript, angular, chat, getstream-io

I'm trying to develop chat application using [getstream.io](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/js/#channel_conversations). In the documentation we can see how to initiate a one-to-one chat like bellow

```
const conversation = client.channel('messaging', null, {
    members: ['ajantha', 'chana'],
})
```

But when I try it I'm getting en error saying **Error: StreamChat error code 4: GetOrCreateChannel failed with error: "When using member based IDs specify at least 2 members**. This is the code sample I'm trying

```
async initChannel() {
    try {
      this.channel = this.client.channel('messaging', null, {
        members: ['ajantha', 'chana'],
    });
      const state = await this.channel.watch();
      console.log('channel was ceated', state);

      this.channel.on('message.new', event => {
        console.log('received a new message', event.message.text);
        console.log(`Now have ${this.channel.state.messages.length} stored in local state`);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error initiating channel', e);
    }
  }
```

Does anyone know Why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: the question only applies to old version of the JS client. The JS client now supports a more friendly signature for `client.channel`. The code below creates a channel without an ID and with two members:

```
const conversation = client.channel('messaging', {
    members: ['ajantha', 'chana'],
})
```

If you pass `null` as the ID argument, that will also work.

Comment: this is creating a unreadable channel id. seems like I have to set a channel by my-self, may be the username of other person that I'm gonna chat. But anyway thank again

Comment: that's the channel unique ID; you can add a custom attributes like name for rendering purposes (often you simply use the name of the channel members as display name)